# Launch Firefox in the same tab

Tags: java, runtime.exec

Problem Description: On my user's machine the default browser is IE 7. Because of security reasons the default browser cannot be changed. On the click of another application  on my user's machine, my application gets launched. My application gets launched in IE 7. In my application I provide users the ability to launch firefox on the click of a button. I am using java to launch a New Firefox Window.

```
String url = "www.google.com";
String[] cmdArray = new String[2];
cmdArray[0] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
cmdArray[1] = url;

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
```

The above piece of code works, however it opens a new Firefox tab every time. 
Is there any way to check if Firefox is already running (with a specific url), then open the 'url' in the same tab?

If this is not possible to achieve in java, can this be achieved in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can call with -new-tab option:

```
firefox.exe -new-tab www.google.com
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: The -new-tab option opens a new tab, however, I would like the open the 'url' in the SAME tab.

Comment: You mean always in the same tab? How the program would know which tab you want this time?

Comment: You are right.. I agree.. Is there any way way, I can close the existing Firefox window and then reopen a new one?

Comment: I know this is possible, but I don't know how. You probably need to use WinAPI.